# Angularjs [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider external module

Tags: angularjs

i have a project that consists of modular angularjs sub apps.
Sub apps reside in their own folders relative the root app folder. 
The problem is that i want to include an external module (satellizer) via bower. The module has downloaded correctly and the bower components get injected to the html via gulp/wiredep. All good so far.

The structure of an app with a controller is as follows:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('foo.bar')
    .filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
        return function (input, attribute) {
            if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

            var array = [];
            for (var objectKey in input) {
                array.push(input[objectKey]);
            }

            array.sort(function (a, b) {
                a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
                b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
                return a - b;
            });
            return array;
        }
    })
    .controller('FoobarController', FoobarController);

FoobarController.$inject = ['logger', '$q', 'dataservice', '$stateParams', 'fooBarHandler', '$location', 'satellizer'];
/* @ngInject */
function FoobarController(logger, $q, dataservice, $stateParams, fooBarHandler, $location, $authProvider) {
    var vm = this;
    fooBarHandler.includeIn(vm, dataservice);

    vm.authorize = authorize;


    }        
}
```

Problem is that angular keeps saying that satellizer is an unknown provider (Unknown provider: satellizerProvider <- satellizer <- FooBarController)
for the sake of brevity i omitted a lot of code from the controller implementation.

i also tried to wire up the dependency via array dependency like so:

```
 angular
    .module('foo.bar', ['satellizer'])
    .filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
        return function (input, attribute) {
            if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

            var array = [];
            for (var objectKey in input) {
                array.push(input[objectKey]);
            }

            array.sort(function (a, b) {
                a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
                b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
                return a - b;
            });
            return array;
        }
    })
```

but still no luck.

Comment: try this one `angular.module('foo.bar', ['satellizer'])`

Comment: I hope you imported satellizer in your html file as well.

Comment: yes i imported satellizer in my html file. Gets wired up via gulp build based on bower.json.

i also tried including satellizer via array dependency but then the satellizer variable is undefined

Comment: Did you config it? As in `angular.module('foo.bar', ['satellizer']).config($authProvider){ $authProvider.provider({ })}`. Then use it in your controller. Like `$auth.authenticate(provider)`

Comment: No i didn't config it before but i tried it based on your comment, still no luck. The $auth varaible still is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working.
After digging trough the source of satellizer i realized i needed to inject from a provider. Satellizer has defined it's provider as '$auth'. So after i changed the line

```
FooBarController.$inject = ['logger', '$q', 'dataservice', '$stateParams', 'fooBarHandler', '$location', 'satellizer];
```

to

```
FooBarController.$inject = ['logger', '$q', 'dataservice', '$stateParams', 'fooBarHandler', '$location', '$auth];
```

it worked